# how to get specific network adapter details with get-netipaddress and where-object

Tags: powershell, ip-address

I am trying to get only IPv4 address details of one of my ethernet adapters. I need to filter the result with `where-object`. But whenever I try to add multiple parameters to `where`, I receive an error.

```
Get-NetIpAddress | where { $_.Interfaceindex -EQ 2 -and $_.AddressFamily -EQ IPv4 }
```

This command shows this error.
[image]

I can get the same result by just typing:

```
Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 2 -AddressFamily IPv4
```

But I need to get the result by using `where-object`. Is there any way to do so? I am just learning powershell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, I've added in quotes as you had missed them on your one. I've also added in brackets, to split up the -and it's a bit more visually appealing to see what you're doing to each segment of the code.

```
Get-NetIpAddress | Where-Object {($_.Interfaceindex -eq "2") -and ($_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4")}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add quote to string ipv4

```
Get-NetIpAddress | where { $_.Interfaceindex -EQ 2 -and $_.AddressFamily -EQ "IPv4" }
```

Comment: its also working.. can you explain a little? why we need to add quote ?

Comment: because without quote, PowerShell interpreter try to cast into numeric value